# Perpendicular Magnitudes

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, projection-matrices

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOvdV.png)

Would the magnitude of the combined individual magnitudes just be zero due to there inner products?

Comment: You will need to be more specific

Comment: @DrPeterMcGowan say if ||x|| = 3, ||y|| = 4. x and y are perpendicular vectors. What is ||x+y||. My question is how I can make use of the information that X and Y are perpendicular vectors to solve ||X+Y||

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$||x+y||^2=$$
$$(x+y)\cdot(x+y)=$$
$$(x+y)\cdot x + (x+y) \cdot y=$$
$$x\cdot x+y \cdot x + x \cdot y + y \cdot y=$$
$$x \cdot x + 2(x \cdot y)+y\cdot y=...$$

Comment: so in this case we have ||x+y||. From what you've written, we can simply break this down into (x+y). So would the magnitude be 7

Comment: @DoofusAnarchy. No: $x \cdot x=||x||^2=4^2...$

Comment: I have 
||x||^2 + ||y||^2 + 2<x,y> =
radical(||x||^2 + ||y||^2)) = 
radical(16+9) = 
radicla(25) = 5

Comment: @DoofusAnarchy Yes, the answer is $||x+y||=5$.